# How to map docker-compose services to jenkins pipeline stages?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

[image: model how it should work]

I need each stage in docker-compose to be visualized in jenkins pipeline, is there any way to do that?

I tried to install docker-compose plugin, and start services from it:

```
step([$class: 'DockerComposeBuilder', dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml', option: [$class: 'StartAllServices'], useCustomDockerComposeFile: true])
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

To map docker-compose services to Jenkins pipeline stages, you can follow the below steps:

1. You need to ensure that your Docker Compose plugin **installed** in Jenkins. Then, **create** a JenkinsFile in your project repo to define Jekins pipeline stages and steps.

Define stages in JenkinsFile will be similar to be below code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Your build steps here
            }
        }

        stage('Start Services') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Start Docker Compose services
                    sh 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                // Your test steps here
            }
        }

        stage('Stop Services') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Stop Docker Compose services
                    sh 'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Therefore, instead of using the *DockerComposeBuilder* step, **use the *dockerCompose* step** provided by the Docker Compose plugin.

Your code should be similar to the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Your build steps here
            }
        }

        stage('Start Services') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Start Docker Compose services
                    dockerCompose(
                        credentialsId: 'docker-hub-credentials',
                        dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml',
                        upOptions: '--detach'
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                // Your test steps here
            }
        }

        stage('Stop Services') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Stop Docker Compose services
                    dockerCompose(
                        credentialsId: 'docker-hub-credentials',
                        dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml',
                        downOptions: ''
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Now, at this stage. You will need to **replace** 'docker-hub-credentials' with the ID of your Docker Hub credentials if your Docker Compose setup involves pulling images from a private registry.
4. Finally, **create** a new pipeline job in Jenkins and point it to your repository. Because Jenkins need to use the Jenkinsfile in your repository to run the pipeline. This also help when you **trigger the Jenkins pipeline**, each stage will correspond to a specific Docker Compose operation, and you should see the visualization of the stages in the Jenkins UI.

Comment: i've installed Docker Compose Build Step Plugin, but there's no "dockerCompose()" step, which plugin is that?

Comment: Install Docker compose plugin from your Jenkins Plugin Manager.

Comment: I dont have any Docker compose plugin in my package manager, when im searching for "Docker compose", it gives me only one plugin that i've already had - "Docker Compose Build Step Plugin"

Comment: You can install the plugin from the Jenkins web UI by following these steps:

Navigate to the Manage Jenkins > Plugins page in the web UI.
Click on the Advanced tab.
Choose the .hpi file from your system or enter a URL to the archive file under the Deploy Plugin section.
Install the plugin file.